# Migrate All App Likes in One Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, migrate

Can i migrate all likes from my applications in one page?
Because all my applications are the same name..\
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No - it is not possible to migrate likes at all... The fact that the pages/apps have the same name is purely coincidental.